# Can't find pandas in data nitro

Tags: python, pandas, datanitro

when I try to import pandas using the data nitro shell, I get the error that there is no module named pandas.

I have pandas through the canopy distribution, but somehow the data nitro shell isn't "finding" it.

I suspect this has to do with the directory in which pandas is stored, but I don't know how to "extract" pandas from that directory and put it into the appropriate directory for data nitro.

Any ideas would be super appreciated. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

DataNitro is probably using a different copy of Python on your machine. Go to Settings in the DataNitro ribbon, uncheck "use default Python", and select the Canopy python directory manually. Then, restart Excel and see if importing works.

Comment: You are amazing - thank you so much. Worked perfectly. Note, I had to use sys.executable() in order to find the exact path and then paste this into datanitro box.